# Google Analytics-like product with the ability to push my own data

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

we are looking for a google analytics-like product but we would like to have the ability to push our own data and analyze them. For instance, we work a lot with affiliates where a visitors visit our site, find some product, visit the owner's website and buy it (that's kind of our funnel here).

We can measure everything within our website, but for those external sales, we get a weekly report. We are looking to import (through some web service or something) those reports into the X analytics product and visualize the complete funnel, conversion rates etc.

Is there such a tool in the market?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many such tools available out there, personal reccomendations would include and the semi-defunct omniture and webtrends, but these are fairly expensive.

Take a look at [google's product line up.](http://www.google.com/analytics/index.html) They do offer self hosted analytics via Urchin 7 and you can do the kind of analysis you want to with their api's.

Also have a look at the following links about [offline marketing with google analytics](http://www.advanced-web-metrics.com/blog/2010/09/27/tracking-offline-marketing-with-google-analytics-whitepaper/) and an [open source plugin for pulling online data into excel](http://excellentanalytics.com/) as these may offer you some ideas.